# Network request is fetched multiple times in CoroutineWorker

Tags: android, kotlin, worker

I have setup the worker class, my intent was to fetch data from the web each 24 hours and i want to get a notification with fetched data. I used periodic work request. My app behavior is weird, notifications fire off only when i start the app. And when app is created, i receive multiple notifications with the data i want. I want only one notification each 24 hours.

Here is my worker class code

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
class PeriodicWork(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {

    private val repository =
        Repository(Database.invoke(applicationContext))

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        try {
            val notificationString = getNotificationResponse().body()!!.value

            val notification =
                NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawable)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification")
                    .setContentText(notificationString)
                    .setStyle(
                        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(notificationString)
                    )
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .build()

            createNotificationChannel()
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
                notify(1, notification)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }

        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
            "New Notification",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        ).apply {
            description = "Notification channel"
        }

        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}

    private suspend fun getNotificationResponse(): Response<WantedData> {
        val notificationResponse =
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.getRandomString() }
        repository.saveString(notificationResponse.body()!!)

        return notificationResponse
    }

}
```

MainActivity part of code where i instantiate worker in a function which i call in onCreate lifecycle method

```
    private fun setupPeriodicRequest() {

        val periodicRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<PeriodicWork>(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance()
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "Periodic Notification",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                periodicRequest
            )
    }
```

If needed i can provide more info, thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with multiple network calls. The setup within the worker class was bad. When i put createNotificationChannel() function above network call the behavior i was experiencing disappeared. I would guess that app was making network calls as long as worker did not do its supposed job. In my case i had network call on first line and it would fire off network request until the notification was created.

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    try {
        createNotificationChannel()

        val notificationString = getNotificationResponse().body()!!.value

        val notification =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawable)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText(notificationString)
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(notificationString)
                )
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build()

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
            notify(1, notification)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you instantiate worker in `setupPeriodicRequest` function. You're passing `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE` in your `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork` function.
Instead, you should use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP` that will only create WorkRequest if not exists.

So, this is how your `setupPeriodicRequest` function should look like:

```
private fun setupPeriodicRequest() {
    val periodicRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<PeriodicWork>(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                         .build()
    WorkManager.getInstance()
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "Periodic Notification",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            periodicRequest
        )
}
```

From the **code documentation** about `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy`:

```
public enum ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy {

    /**
     * If there is existing pending (uncompleted) work with the same unique 
     * name, cancel and delete it. Then, insert the newly-specified work.
     */
    REPLACE,

    /**
     * If there is existing pending (uncompleted) work with the same unique 
     * name, do nothing.
     * Otherwise, insert the newly-specified work.
     */
    KEEP
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, it did not solve my problem, notifications appear less randomly, but i still get multiple network calls launched